# Are flags completely anonymous?

Tags: support, flags

Are flags on Stack Overflow completely anonymous? Obviously, the user whose post or comment got flagged can’t see or know who flagged it. The [What is flagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) page doesn’t say anything about flags being anonymous. Can other users (like high-rep users) see who flagged a post?

Comment: Flags are not anonymous because moderators and CMs can see your flags.

Comment: Maybe you meant to ask if it's public?

Comment: @Dharman Yes, that’s what I meant

Comment: Only you, moderators/CMs, and those with direct access to the database(s) can see *your* flags. The most we can see about flags you raise is the number of "helpful" flags you have raised.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flags are not anonymous to users with diamonds (♦), such as moderators and some staff like Community Managers. Diamond users can see who raised a flag, and can see all flags

- for a given post
- raised by a user (i.e. they  can see the page where you can see your own flags)
- raised on posts made by that user

No other users can see your flags. Diamond users will only discuss flags with you in a private setting, unless you come to a public place like Meta or a public chat room and discuss them there (i.e. you post a Meta question about a flag you raised).